# how to fix the data is empty due to asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, fetch

There is a page that displays No user when there is no data in the database. When there is data in the database, the real data is displayed. The code is as follows

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch(`/users`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        }
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();

        if (data.success) {
          setUsers(data.users);
        }

      } else {
        console.log('Other HTTP Error:', response.status);
      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching users:', error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  fetchData();
}, [token]);


const userList = () => {

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  const activedUsers = users
  .filter((user) => user.status === 1);

  if (activedUsers.length === 0) {
    return(
      <>
      {activedUsers.length === 0 &&
        <div>No user</div>
      }
      </>
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
      {activedUsers.map((user) => (
        <div key={user.userID}>
          <Link to={`/user/${user.userID}`}>{user.Name}</Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

In the situation I am encountering now, when entering the page for the first time, 'No user' will always flash quickly, then Loading will appear, and then the real data will appear. Every time I refresh the page, this problem occurs.

The correct situation should be to display loading first, then if there is a user, display the user, if there is no user, display no user.

Any ideas?

Comment: `const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you, my mistake. Kind of tired. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

For loading in first place, you have set `isLoading` `true` when you have defined it.

Example:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
```